# Simple 3D app Design Pattern

Tags: actionscript-3, model-view-controller, design-patterns, 3d

Im attempting to convert a simple 3D room explorer/configurator app that is a hacky mess into something a little better.

I have now begun separating it out using an MVC pattern, but have found a major performance decrease. I think this is down to the Controller updating the camera parameters in the Model, which is then notifying the view, which in turn requests these new values.

Should this be an issue, or am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

You may be going about it the wrong way. Try to implement a few tests to identify where the performance drop happens. What's your IDE , can you use a profiler?

Comment: Im using flashdevelop, using the profiler I can see object count, mem usuage etc but not sure how to use it to help with this problem?